# Ayuda creacion de aplicacion

Tags: php, mysql

Quiero crear una aplicación tipo CRUD para listar información de los usuarios de la compañía, la cosa es que esta aplicación solo la utilizarían unas 5 personas en la empresa y me dicen que no es necesario que este online en la web.

Se un poco de php y mysql, quería saber cual seria la mejor opción para realizarla, ¿es posible simplemente hostearla atraves de wamp y que los usuarios se conecten por localhost a la aplicación dentro de la misma empresa?

Comment: La mejor opción es terceriar.

Answer (score 0):

Buenos días Rotsen!

Un excelente framework para crear aplicaciones en PHP es www.symfony.es

Sin embargo, podrías también optar por desarrollar dentro del framework .Net de Microsoft (en ASP.Net). Suele ser muy adecuado para comenzar con el desarrollo y eficiente para aplicaciones pequeñas.

No conozco el nivel de expertiz que posee en el desarrollo de software, pero tené en cuenta que se suele estudiar varios años para programar aplicaciones. Es fundamental tener una base de conocimiento sobre cómo funcionan los ordenadores y luego sobre las bases de la algorítmica.

En cuanto al tema del *hosting*, la respuesta es sí. Podrías *hostearla* vos mismo en un servidor local en la empresa. Sin embargo, esto no tiene relación con que sólo será usada por pocos usuarios, dado que depende de la arquitectura informática que montes limitarás los usuarios que soporte. Me refiero a que existen grandes centro de datos con servidores muy potentes que son utilizados de forma local. A su vez existen hosting con diferentes tipos de potencia computacional que pueden albergar diferentes "tamaños" de aplicaciones. Con todo esto voy a que primero deberías ver qué ordenadores tenés como para montar el servidor. Siempre recomiendo tener un ordenador dedicado a ser servidor y no montar la base de datos y el servidor web en un ordenador utilizado por usuarios.

Por último, hosteandola vos mismo en la empresa también podrías hacer que esté "online". Seguramente te referís a que pueda ser accedida desde Internet, entonces para eso podrías forwardear el puerto en el router de la empresa hacia el servidor web y obtener un puntero dinámico gratuito y así acceder a la aplicación desde cualquier lado. Me refiero a que no es condición necesaria que contrates un hosting para acceder a la aplicación desde cualquier lado.

Answer (score 0):

> ¿es posible simplemente hostearla atraves de wamp y que los usuarios se conecten por localhost a la aplicación dentro de la misma empresa?

la respuesta es si, pero no seria por localhost accederias por ip si estan dentro de la misma red no tendras problemas